# Is there a classification of Metric Spaces?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

As in group theory, there is a concept of isomorphism between metric spaces called isometry.
Two metric spaces $X$ and $Y$ are isometric if there is a function that perserves the distance of two elements. That function is called isometry.

The thing is that properties of metric spaces (completeness, compactness, connectedness, etc.) are preserved  under isometry.

So, thinking about the classification of finite simple groups, I was wondering if there is any classification of Metric Spaces up to isometry, or at least a specific category of Metric Spaces (like finite simple groups in Group Theory). Also, I am interested if there is a more general topological classification of Metric Spaces up to homeomorphism (isomorphism in topology).

Comment: Well, from a set theory point of view, finite simple groups are a rather small set of examples, while there cant possibly be a set of metric spaces, as you can equip an arbitrary set with the discrete metric. You have to refine your question to a much smaller class of metric spaces to even hope to get a classification theorem...

Comment: Take a look at [this survey](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.01750.pdf)

Comment: Properties of metric spaces like completeness  **are not preserved** under homeomorphisms. They are preserved under surjective isometries.

Comment: Actually homeomorphisms are isomorphisms of topologies (in this case, the topologies induced by the respective metric). Isomorphisms of metric spaces are known as isometries.

Comment: http://www.phy.olemiss.edu/~luca/Topics/d/distance_types.html

Comment: I see. Sorry for the confusion. In one Metric Space lecture we were explained that  homeomorphisms act like isomorphism. I think it was meant topologically speaking. Nevertheless, compactedness and connectedness still hold.

Comment: I have rephrased the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's too ambitious, there is an enormous variety of metric spaces. But if you restrict to specific classes, then a lot has been done. I can think of two examples: Hilbert spaces and geodesic surfaces. These are completely classified.

Hilbert spaces are vector spaces equipped with a scalar product, which induces a norm, hence a distance and so a structure of metric space, which is required to be complete. Hilbert spaces are completely characterized up to isomorphism (a stronger form of isometry); in particular, any **separable** real Hilbert space is isomorphic to 
$$
\ell^2:=\left\{\boldsymbol{x}=(x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots)\ :\ x_j\in\mathbb R,\ \sum_{j=1}^\infty x_j^2<\infty\right\},$$
where the scalar product is given by 
$$
\langle \boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{y}\rangle = \sum_{j=1}^\infty x_j y_j.$$ 
(Non-separable Hilbert spaces are classified in terms of cardinality of their orthonormal bases. Also, the same result holds in the complex case, with obvious modifications).

Geodesic surfaces are something I know less. I will refer to [this beautiful note](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/ghys/articles/disque-poincare.pdf) of Etienne Ghys, section 3. It is in French, but I am sure I have seen an English translation on the net.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, but two metrics are equivalent iff there are $m, M$ such that $1/md'(x,y)\le d(x,y)\le Md'(x,y)$ for all $x,y\in X$.

Comment: The issue with this concept is that it is too specific. We are forced to have the same set for the two metrics ($X$). A better concept is that of isometry, that allows to make isomorphisms between metric spaces coming from different sets. Also, homeomorphism is a kind of isomorphism, but it does not necessarily preserves properties of metric spaces like completeness, so it is too broad.

Comment: There are Banach spaces, Hilbert spaces, we have $L^p$ duality.  The category $\bf{Met}$ was first studied in $1964$ by Isbell.  The objects are metric spaces and the morphisms are metric maps, continuous functions that don't increase the distance between any pair of points.